# While loop with two true conditions but it only validate one

Tags: c#, while-loop

I need the code to run until both conditions at the while are true, I am using logical AND (&&):

```
while ((A.i != B.i) && (A.j != B.j))
{
    // do something
}
```

at the run, the loop stops if

```
A.i=B.i
```

without checking the second condition, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `A.i=B.i` then both conditions are not true.

Comment: @DourHighArch how so?

Comment: Because `A.i != B.i` is false, so at least one condition is not true. If one condition is not true, then both conditions cannot be true.

Comment: It is doing exactly what you've told it to do.  What behavior do you expect?

Comment: What are the both conditions that need to be true?

Comment: You seem to not understand either what `&&` means or what `while` means. Can you describe what you believe them to mean, and we can tell you where you are wrong?

Comment: What I want to achieve is:
if A.i = B.i AND A.j=B.j then break the loop

Comment: @HishamSiam: Then start by writing exactly that:  `while(true) { if (a.i == b.i && a.j == b.j) break;  ... body of loop here ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a conditional statement where the `&&` operator is used, the second condition is only evaluated if the first one is `true`. That is why when `A.i==B.i` you immediately break out of the check

"I need the code to run until both conditions at the while are true"

That confuses me, because if you want a `while` loop to run **until** certain conditions are `true`, then you would not want those conditions to be evaluated in the `while()` statement..

If you want your code to run **UNTIL** both of those conditions are true, then it really should be:

```
// Keep running while EITHER A.i is equal to B.i OR A.j is equal to B.j
while ((A.i == B.i) || (A.j == B.j))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You flipped his != to == which breaks on the OR here

Comment: OP said he wants the loop to run until those conditions are both met, so hes basically saying he wants the loop to run until `A.i is not equal to B.i and A.j is not equal to B.j` which is what that loop checks.. if either `A.i == B.i` OR `A.j == B.j` the loop will continue

Answer (score 3):

Switch your `&&` to `||`

Your loop says "while A.i is not equal to B.i AND A.J is not equal to B.j" loop. Once A.i equal B.i that statement is no longer true, so the loop exits (it doesn't actually care about the second equality at that point). By using an OR it will loop until both conditions are false.

Comment: I see your point..

Answer (score 1):

Not clear but I suspect this is what you are looking for

```
while ( !(A.i == B.i && A.j == B.j) )
```

Which is the same as

```
while ( A.i != B.i || A.j != B.j) )
```

I think?

Answer (score 1):

OP, your question isn't very clear, but I'm pretty sure you are up against one of two problems.

1. This is a very common logic error

   ```
   while (a == b) || (c == d)
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   until (a != b) && (c != d)
   ```

   Meanwhile,

   ```
   while (a != b) && (c != d)
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   until (a == b) || (c == d)
   ```

   Notice how when you switch from `==` to `!=`, you also need to switch `&&` for `||`.  A lot of devs miss this very obvious sort of logic flip (see [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)).  Anyway, you just need to think the logic through.  From your post, it is not clear what you are intending, but you might just need to switch `&&` for `||`.
2. Short circuit evaluation

   Sounds like you wanted the second half of the logic to run, perhaps because the getter for `j` has some side effect that you want (which by the way isn't a great idea).

   If you want the second half to always run, you should use `|` instead of `||`.  The `||` operator doesn't bother with the right hand side if the left hand side is true.  Similarly, the `&&` operator doesn't bother with the right hand side if the left hand side is false.  This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

Because A.i != B.i evaluates to false so no need to complete the condition